# How can I remove newlines if they aren't at the beginning or at the end of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, newline, strip

How can I remove \n from this example string? (In Python 3)

```
'Word 1\nWord 2'
```

I tried using **.strip** but it can only remove \n if its at the beginning or at the end of the string... 
**I also tried:**

```
string.replace('\\n', '')
```

But that doesn't seem to work either...

Answer (score 3):

`replace` worked for me, make sure you did the following:

```
a = 'Word 1\nWord 2'
a = a.replace("\n", "") #instead of just a.replace("\n", "")
```

Returns: `'Word 1Word 2'`

Answer (score 0):

you are using double `\\` on newline here-> `string.replace('\\n', '')` use '"\n"' instead

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
string.replace('\\n', '')
```

with this:

```
string = string.replace('\n', '') #you used double slashes for some reason
```

When you uses the double slashes, it thought you were looking to replace these two characters when they're in order: `\n`. But you want to replace a newline, so you don't need to add the extra slash.

Answer (score -1):

```
y=""
for x in 'Word 1\nWord 2':
    if(x != "/n"):
       y=y+x
print(y)
```

You can use this code it will print

```
Word1
Word2
```

Hope this might be helpful.